# How to add an username from Firebase Auth to Firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I dont want to use textfield to insert name, rather than to upload it automatically in the firebase storage along with the form!!

```dart
onPressed: () {
    final snackBar = SnackBar(
                        content: const Text('Successfully Uploaded!!!'),
                        action: SnackBarAction(onPressed: () {}, label: 'Undo',),
                     );
    final post = Post(
                  location: locationController.text,
                  type: typeController.text,
                  facilities: facilitiesController.text,
                  price: int.parse(priceController.text),
                  contact: int.parse(contactController.text),
                  date_time: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
                  // name: nameController.text,
                  name: User.getDisplayName(),
                );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not upload your text to firebase storage because it only saves only files like images and documents, but it can be saved to firebase-realtime database or firestore, you can store you name to firestore by using this

```
final snackBar = SnackBar(
                    content: const Text('Successfully Uploaded!!!'),
                    action: SnackBarAction(onPressed: () {}, label: 'Undo',),
                 );
final post = Post(
              location: locationController.text,
              type: typeController.text,
              facilities: facilitiesController.text,
              price: int.parse(priceController.text),
              contact: int.parse(contactController.text),
              date_time: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
              // name: nameController.text,
              name: User.getDisplayName(),
            );
            FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("userName").add(
              name: //yourname
              ;
            );
```